# PHP and SQL echo using two parameters

Tags: php, sql

I have an SQL database which i populate with the following

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("stingin_epanic", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO sms_sent (smsmsisdn, member_name, member_id, dealer, sms)
VALUES

('$_POST[smsmsisdn]','$_POST[member_name]','$_POST[member_id]','$_POST[dealer]','$_POST[sms]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "SMS Submitted";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

My columns are as follow in the Table

smsmsisdn / sms / id / member_msisdn / member_id / member_name / dealer

As there will be numerous information to the same user but the SMS details change I need to display the msg on the id as well as the personal details as shown below in the code.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "****"; // Mysql username
$password = "****"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "****"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "sms_sent"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id='$member_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['msisdn'] = "27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);
?>
```

I echo the SQL as follow:

```
value="<? echo $rows['member_msisdn']; ?>
```

Problem I am having is there are numerous inputs for a specific number on the form I send the details to the new php screen as such

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="sms_send.php">
```

It does however Echo the right information for the member_msisdn and the other fields as they are common but the SMS field is different for each how do I notify the system I want to use the specific id it just created to only display that row of date.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Also, SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated.

you need replace `$member_id` to `$id` in

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id='$id'";
```

here is new code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "****"; // Mysql username
$password = "****"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "****"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "sms_sent"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['msisdn'] = "27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);
?>
```

**Note :** you have sql injection in your code , don't pass value directly to mysql if you are not sure about it

change `$id = $_GET['id'];` to

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

now `$id` is safe.